# Why does this logon trigger work in one server but not another?

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-11g

I created the below trigger in the same manner in the SYS schema on two different Oracle 11g servers, without any errors.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGON_TRG 
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
    if (user in ('mytestro', 'mytestrw')) then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = mytest';
    end if;
exception 
  when others 
    then null; -- prevent a login failure due to an exception
END logon_trg;
/`

On one server I can tell it is working since I can select any table in mytest as soon as I logon with either account.  On the other server it says the table does not exist (ORA-00942).  If I issue `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = mytest;` manually I can access the table, so it seems the trigger is not firing.

Comment: Just to confirm: you've double-checked to be sure that the server is seeing your login name as one of those two names on the other server?

Comment: If you mean to ask if the login names are identical, and have been verified by logging in, yes.

Comment: Make sure auditing is enabled, then check DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL.  I strongly suspect that in spite of your assertion otherwise, you are not logging on as who you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your trigger is enabled, I am surprised at your trigger working at all.

Usernames are case-insensitive by default and treated as uppercase strings internally. If you create a user called `mytestro` or `mytestrw`, the actual usernames will be `MYTESTRO` and `MYTESTRW`. Normally, a condition like the one in your `if` statement, will be false.

Sure, it is possible to create case-sensivite, lowercase usernames, but that is quite rare and I consider it bad practice, because it has no benefits, it just makes administration cumbersome.

Instead of:

```
create user mytestro ...
```

You can use:

```
create user "mytestro" ...
```

The former creates a user called `MYTESTRO`. The latter creates a user `mytestro`. These are not identical.

The first one behaves as:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MYTESTRO"
```

While the second one behaves as:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "mytestro"
```

You can use the above to check the actual usernames when logged in (or `select user from dual` if your client does not support `show`). Your trigger in its current form does not work with the first user above, and does work with the second user above.

Comment: This was indeed the case!  I got `USER is "MYTESTRO"`. Changing the trigger to look for that did the trick.  Of course the mystery now is how this works on my other server, with the same `SHOW USER` output and the old trigger code.